# How to get admin user kubeconfig

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-aks, azure-rm

I am using azure aks and deployed it by using terraform module, I have executed successfully. following below documents.

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/kubernetes-cluster-with-aks-and-terraform

But the problem is that I want to save kubeconfig of admin user.Below is the code I have written.  I am not able to get kubeconfig file of admin user.

```
==============================================

resource "null_resource" "kubeconfig_save" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
           rm -rf /tmp/kubeconfig && \
           echo "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config_raw}" > /tmp/kubeconfig
    EOT
    }
}
==================================================
```

I need kubeconfig with admin user.

Comment: You probably will have to wait for this issue: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2421 to be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this:

```
output "kubeConfig" {
  value = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config_raw}"
}
```

if that doesnt work try outputting it similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/andywirv/d61ebaaef0aa99d1370899d6138616be) example.

and then run:

```
terraform output kubeConfig > file.tmp
```